# Is a popover a good way to present short pieces of information on a website?

Tags: website-design, usability, accessibility, design

I'm currently designing a website on which I have to include the obligatory legalese. So: copyright info, privacy policy etc. There's not a whole lot of text though, at best two paragraphs of text for each link. So I'd like to *prevent* creating an entirely separate page for each link because these pages would look ugly and empty with only two paragraphs of text (with my current design at least).

I was thinking of doing something like a popover or an expanding area, which would show the info when visitors click on said links, without taking them to another page.

- Would there be any objections to doing this from an accessibility or design perspective (because I know there's kind of a taboo on popups, which are sort of related to my solution)?
- What solution would you suggest for presenting this kind of information?

Comment: Could you not combine the legal/copyright/privacy/T&C/disclaimer/E&OE/cookie info/complaints/whatever info all on one page - even though you may use more than one link to get there.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that. I could use anchors to redirect to a specific area on the page. Would you say that's better than a popover/expanding area?

Comment: I'd say it's more future proof, more accessible and more mobile friendly, not to mention the element of legally critical content being available even to those with popup blockers, javascript switched off, etc... but see what others say here too.

Comment: You also have to test with more browsers e.g. phone browsers do not always show popups which means users cannot see the legalise which might be illegal in some places.

Comment: Do users need to be able to access this information without leaving the current context, i.e. when completing a task that they would not want to abandon?

Comment: @MattObee, no not really. It's not like they have to complete sales transactions or registrations or anything. The website as a whole is purely informational (so not a lot of interactivity).

Comment: @RogerAttrill hasn't left his comment as an answer, but I would completely agree with all his points. A separate page with anchor links to the relevant areas is ideal here. It's accessible, it doesn't have any SEO impact (unless you *really* need your cookie info to be on a separate page to the EULA!) and is much easier to maintain.

Comment: @JonW I took that as a cue to put my comments into an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my comments above seem to present a reasonable answer, I've made it so!

I'd recommend combining the legal/copyright/privacy/T&C/disclaimer/E&OE/cookie info/complaints/whatever information onto one page (with anchor points) - even though you may use more than one link to get there. It then presents a common point of reference for all related information.

It's more future proof (more easily maintained and extended), more accessible, and more mobile friendly, not to mention the element of legally critical content being available even to those with popup blockers, javascript switched off, etc.

Comment: Some good points here! I think it belongs as a comment more than an answer though. ;)

Comment: @JonW - haha - you're a one you are. (Whatever that means!)

Answer (score 2):

For mobile browsers, I wouldn't count on it being visible at all if you did a popover, which defeats the purpose of putting important context inside your popovers... and actually reinforces something important, which is **if it's important, don't hide it,** whether in a popover, tooltip, or otherwise.

Popovers, tooltips, collapsing / expanding areas, etc. are meant as reinforcements of information the user should already have -- so if you insist on doing it, I certainly wouldn't make it the *only* way to read that information.